# setup connection to ldap oracle server for JPA project

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jpa, ldap

I am trying to connect to an Ldap oracle server for my JPA project in Eclipse in order to create entity classes from tables. The following connection url for the server works in my java code for db operations.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://mdaoid.mdanderson.org:389/risdev3, cn=OracleContext,dc=mdacc,dc=tmc,dc=edu
```

The connection for SQL Developer is set up as follows:
[image]

However I could not connect to DB in Eclipse. All the fields are required. But I don't know what SID is supposed to be. Although SQL Developer does use port 1521, there is another port 389 in the url as well.

[image]
In the profile window, the url is not something I can edit. Instead it is a combination of all the fields. No matter what I do, there is no way to get the exact same URL as what is used in Java code. It always says "Ping failed". How exactly should I set up connection to LDAP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... Go to Window > Preferences > Data Management > Connectivity > Driver Definitions.

[image]

In there, add a new driver definition... Pick Oracle Other Driver...

[image]

Add the jars that you use for connecting to the LDAP Server from code in the "Jar List" Tab... and then complete the properties Tab with your special connection url...

[image]

And finally, create/test the connection with the "connection wizzard" and using the driver definition that was defined by you previously...